# Get number of projects and average completion rate

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some project data. One column contains "Completion %". By default the value is set to 0. What is the best way to structure the mySQL query and write a code to get the following 3 values:

- total users (every row WHERE PROJECT = 5)
- participants (WHERE PROJECT = 5 AND completion != 0)
- average completion rate (average of the % of participants)

I don't think I can do it all in a single query...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT project_id,
  COUNT(*) AS total_users,
  COUNT(IF(completion != 0, rowID, NULL)) AS participants,
  AVG(IF(completion != 0, completion, NULL)) AS average_completion_rate
FROM Projects
WHERE project_id = 5
GROUP BY project_id;
```

It would be helpful in the future if you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` of your table and include it in your question.

---

Re comment:  So it sounds like your table is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Projects (
  rowID         INT PRIMARY KEY,
  project_id    INT,
  completion    TINYINT
);
```

I have edited my suggested query above to match.

Comment: Wow, this is great! The fields are: rowID PRIMARY INT, project_id INT and completion TINYINT. None are NULL.